# wordpress plugin that make airbnb how it works and help page

Tags: wordpress

I have a website make by wordpress.

1. I want to make a page apprear like when click on "How it works" button on https://www.airbnb.com/ home page.
2. I also want to make help menu and function exactly like that of airbnb.

Do anybody know how to do it? What plug-in might do the almost similar function like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

since you ask for plugin and its hard to explain in details here .

1. it called `slide panel` this is nice plugin like in airbnb [[Demo](http://designify.me/code-snippets/sliding-panel/)] ,[[link](http://designify.me/web-design/simple-modal-like-sliding-panel-with-jquery-and-css3/)]
2. its searchable drop down .. see this [[Demo](http://www.jquery-az.com/boots/demo.php?ex=6.0_6)],[[link](http://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-select-5-beautiful-styles/)]

Comment: thank you so much. could you please name the best slide panel plugin of wordpress which do the most similar job like in airbnb?